# Array has suddenly only one element instead of three elements

Tags: angular, angularjs

I fetch data from a server and use therefore a promise to wait till the data is arrived. Now I'm in the situation that if I go to a page and from their back to the other page, the tasks-Array, that I use to emit the customer tasks to an other component, has if I log it three SelectedCustomerTasks-Elements. But if i want to find the one element of the selected customer i only get an array with just one SelectedCustomerTasks-Element.

This is the console output of the this.customerTasks-Array in the function **findTasksOfCustomer**:

```
0: {customerId: '418', tasks: Array(1), openTasksAmount: 1}
1: {customerId: '503', tasks: Array(1), openTasksAmount: 1}
2: {customerId: '409', tasks: Array(4), openTasksAmount: 3}
```

and this is the console output if I iterate through this array in the function **findTasksOfCustomer**:

```
{customerId: '418', tasks: Array(1), openTasksAmount: 1}
```

I haven't experienced such unusual behavior and I don't know why that happens.

This is my code:

```
  private loadTasks() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var tasks: tasks[] = [];

      this.customers.forEach(async (customer, index) => {
        var tasks = (
          await this._taskClient.getCustomerTasks(customer.customerId).toPromise()
        ).map((x) => JSON.parse(x) as Task);

        var data: SelectedCustomerTasks = {
          customerId: customer.customerId,
          tasks: tasks,
          openTasksAmount: tasks.filter(
            (x) => x.output[0].valueBoolean !== true
          ).length,
        };

        tasks.push(data);

        if (index == this.customers.length - 1) {
          resolve(tasks);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTasks().then((tasks: SelectedCustomerTasks[]) => {
      if (tasks.length > 0) {
        this.customerTasks = tasks;
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("customerId")) {
          this.selectedCustomer = this.customers.find(
            (x) => x.customerId == sessionStorage.getItem("customerId")
          );
          if (this.selectedCustomer) {
            this.emitCustomerData(this.selectedCustomer, false);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

```
private async emitCustomerData(customer: Customer){
 this.selectedCustomerEvent.emit(this.findTasksOfCustomer(customer));
}
```

```
  private findTasksOfCustomer(customer: Customer): SelectedCustomerTasks {
    return this.customerTasks.find((x) => x.customerId == customer.customerId );
  }
```

I've debugged the code.

Comment: I haven't taken a look in depth, but it seems a little odd that you use `await` in your async forEach loop. The execution of this loop will not wait until the previous iteration has finished, which means that your self created Promise will resolve after the first iteration. Can you check if this could be the root cause? Maybe you can decide whether you want to have these calls sequentially (use a regular for loop and await the results) or in parallel (switch to `Promise.all`).

Comment: **NOT** use "var". This create a global variable, use "let" or "constant"

Comment: Thank you @FabianStrathaus. This was the root cause. I changed the code to Promise.all() and now it works.

Comment: Awesome! For completeness I added this as an answer. Feel free to accept it and close your question, if no open topics are left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complete this question, so it can be closed:

Problem was that the `resolve(tasks)` was called inside a for each loop, which means that the for loop did not need to run completely through before `resolve(tasks)` was called. This was leading to an unexpected behavior depending on the order of the asynchronous tasks resolving.

Switching the approach to resolving only after all promises created by `this._taskClient.getCustomerTasks(customer.customerId).toPromise()` are resolved did the trick. Here `Promise.all(...)` was used to collect all promises and wait until all of them are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few things you might want to check:

- You declare two variables `tasks` in your code. Make sure they contain the data you expect them to contain. Maybe choose different names for them to make it more clear that they are different variables.
- The object `data` contains a property `tasks` that points to your variable `tasks` but below you add `data` to `tasks` too. I don't know your use case but this looks supicious.

Tip for debugging: Check all places that access your `tasks`. One of them **has** to modify the array. Remember that some operations on arrays modify the array itself, like `splice`, instead of returning a modified array.